# number of generators of ideal $I$ in $\mathbb{C}[X, Y, Z]$ and dimension of $V(I)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition

According to [this article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0068914), ideals in $\mathbb{C}[X_1, X_2, X_3]$ can be so complicated that for every $m$ one can find an ideal $I$ such that $\mu(I)$, the minimal number of polynomials needed to generate $I$, is at least $m$.

I find this highly counter-intuitive. I do not really need or want to know the proof of the theorem but I *do* want to know where my intuition (expanded below) goes wrong. I hope someone can help me with that much simpler quest.

---

My simplistic intuition is this. If $I$ is generated by $f_1, \ldots, f_m$, with $m > 3$ minimal, then $V(I)$ is the intersection of the hypersurfaces $V(f_1), V(f_2), \ldots, V(f_m)$.

Starting with $V(f_1)$, intersecting it with $V(f_2)$, intersecting the result with $V(f_3)$ etc we will find that the new intersection has either dimension one less than the previous one, or will be identical to the previous one.

Since the $V(f_1)$ live in three dimensional space, we can encounter the first of these cases at most three times before hitting the empty set. But the second case, where $V(f_1, \ldots, f_k) \cap V(f_{k+1})$ equals $V(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$ would show that $f_{k+1}$ was superfluous as a generator of $I$, which would contradict the minimality of $m$.

**So obviously something is wrong, but what?**

---

It am pretty sure that my intuition is correct if we replace 'hypersurface' with 'hyperplane', but in that case there is also no contradiction as ideals generated by linear polynomials have at most three generators (if I am not crazy). So probably the answer has something to do with the fact that not all hypersurfaces are hyperplanes.

But then I still fail to picture a pair of non-equal hypersurfaces whose intersection is still 2-dimensional. Do these exist and is it just my lack of imagination that I cannot find them, or do they indeed not exist and am I misunderstanding something completely different?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks! This points to a different flaw in my intuition than the answer by Sergey below, namely that the part where I say that if $V(f_1, \ldots, f_k) \cap V(f_{k+1}) = V(f_1, \ldots, f_k)$ then $f_{k+1}$ is superfluous as a generator, right? It need not be superfluous because there can be actually different ideals with the same Null set. Is this the correct interpretation of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting with $V(f_1)$, intersecting it with $V(f_2)$, intersecting the result with $V(f_3)$ etc we will find that the new intersection has either dimension one less than the previous one, or **will be identical to the previous one**.

Here's the error. It doesn't have to be identical, it may have less irreducible components while being of the same dimension.

Consider the following example: take varieties cut out in $\mathbb{A^2}$ by $y-x^2=0$ and $y-1=0$. Their intersection consists of two points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$. Intersect it with a variety consisting of a line passing through exactly one of these points, say, $x=1$. The intersection will become strictly smaller while staying of the same dimension. To get higher-dimensional examples you can just consider the same equations in $\mathbb{A}^n$, $n>2$.

Projective subvarieties of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of codimension $k$ such that their ideals can be generated by $k$ elements are called complete intersections, and most varieties are not of this sort. The simplest example I know is the twisted cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3$: it's a degree 3 curve, so for it to be a complete intersection its equations must be of degrees 1 and 3, which would make the whole cubic actually embed into some hyperplane of $\mathbb{P}^3$, and it's easy to see that that's not the case.

Comment: Right, so even if the varieties themselves are irreducible, connected, simply connected, etc their lower dimensional intersections need not be, and leave room for a long list of dimension-preserving steps. Your example is really nice!